# Getting location data from an image (Instagram/JS)

Tags: javascript, loops, location, instagram, geotagging

I've been working on a side project and have hit a roadblock. I can search through tags and display their picture results just fine, but I'd also like to put the details below each picture, specifically the location information. I'm doing this in Javascript, and commented out the lines I believe need to be adjusted, but with the comment marks removed not even the pictures show up. Any tips? A JSON object printed by a call to Instagram returns this data:

```
Object
  - data: Array[20]
    - 0: Object
      + caption: Object
      + comments: Object
        created_time: "1334402906"
        filter: "Nashville"
        id: "169306311223447303_5913362"
      - images: Object
        + low_resolution: Object
        - standard_resolution: Object
          height: 612
          url: "http://distilleryimage7.instagram.com/f3f8d7b2862411e19dc71231380fe523_7.jpg"
          width: 612
        + thumbnail: Object
        + likes: Object
          link: "http://instagr.am/p/JZfzFqtI8H/"
          location: Object
          tags: Array[1]
          type: "image"
          user: Object
```

And my code looks like this:

```
// Instantiate an empty object.
var Instagram = {};

// Small object for holding important configuration data.
Instagram.Config = {
  clientID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  apiHost: 'https://api.instagram.com'
};


// ************************
// ** Main Application Code
// ************************
(function(){
  var photoTemplate, resource;

  function init(){
    bindEventHandlers();
    photoTemplate = _.template($('#photo-template').html());
  }

  function toTemplate(photo){
    photo = {
      count: photo.likes.count,
      avatar: photo.user.profile_picture,
      photo: photo.images.low_resolution.url,
      url: photo.link
      //location: photo.location  <--------------------------This line.
    };

    return photoTemplate(photo);
  }

  function toScreen(photos){
    var photos_html = '';
    //var photos_location = ''; <------------------------This line.

    $('.paginate a').attr('data-max-tag-id', photos.pagination.next_max_id)
                    .fadeIn();

    $.each(photos.data, function(index, photo){
      photos_html += toTemplate(photo);
      //photos_location += toTemplate(photo); <-----------------This line.
    });

    $('div#photos-wrap').append(photos_html);
    //$('div#photos-wrap').append(photos_location) <------------------This line. 
  }


  function generateResource(tag){
    var config = Instagram.Config, url;

    if(typeof tag === 'undefined'){
      throw new Error("Resource requires a tag. Try searching for cherry blossoms.");
    } else {
      // Make sure tag is a string, trim any trailing/leading whitespace and take only the first
      // word, if there are multiple.
      tag = String(tag).trim().split(" ")[0];
    }

    // Configures the URL to search for pictures that fit the tag description.
    url = config.apiHost + "/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?callback=?&client_id=" + config.clientID;

    return function(max_id){
      var next_page;
      if(typeof max_id === 'string' && max_id.trim() !== '') {
        next_page = url + "&max_id=" + max_id;
      }
      return next_page || url;
    };
  }

  function paginate(max_id){
    $.getJSON(generateUrl(tag), toScreen);
  }

  function search(tag){
    resource = generateResource(tag);
    $('.paginate a').hide();
    $('#photos-wrap *').remove();
    fetchPhotos();
  }

  function fetchPhotos(max_id){
    $.getJSON(resource(max_id), toScreen);
  }

  function bindEventHandlers(){
    $('body').on('click', '.paginate a.btn', function(){
      var tagID = $(this).attr('data-max-tag-id');
      fetchPhotos(tagID);
      return false;
    });

    // Bind an event handler to the `submit` event on the form
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){

      // Stop the form from fulfilling its destinty.
      e.preventDefault();

      // Extract the value of the search input text field.
      var tag = $('input.search-tag').val().trim();

      // Invoke `search`, passing `tag` (unless tag is an empty string).
      if(tag) {
        search(tag);
      };

    });

  }

  function showPhoto(p){
    $(p).fadeIn();
  }

  // Public API
  Instagram.App = {
    search: search,
    showPhoto: showPhoto,
    init: init
  };
}());


$(function(){
  Instagram.App.init();

  Instagram.App.search('takoyaki');
});
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of your code? Have you looked in the console to see what errors you have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FNM7G/1/ - Though I screwed up somewhere. Could not remember what the site was for the life of me, so glad you mentioned it. Thanks! I'm not entirely sure about the errors.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to expand on this site: http://grammy.eduvoyage.com/

The functionality is the same, but I want to pull additional information from each of the pictures. At some point too, I want to take those location IDs and display them on Google maps underneath the image.

Comment: So you are using jquery and underscore? I don't see either included in your jsfiddle?

Comment: I should probably mention that I am very new to all this, and just followed a tutorial to get this all set up ^^; This tutorial: http://eduvoyage.com/instagram-search-app.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, as long as the photo has location data, not all of them do

CSS

```
body {
  background: #e3e8ec url(http://grammy.eduvoyage.com/images/tile.png) repeat 50% 0;
}
#search {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -130px;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
}

.search-wrap {
  background: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#photos-wrap {
  width: 810px;
  margin: 70px auto 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.photo .avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 11px;
  right: 8px;
  background: white;
}

.photo  {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.photo .heart {
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: white url('http://grammy.eduvoyage.com/images/fav.png') no-repeat 2px 0;
}

.paginate {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.location {
    position: relative;
    top: -48px;
    left: 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
      <div id='photos-wrap'>
      </div>

      <div class='paginate'>
        <a class='btn'  style='display:none;' data-max-tag-id='' href='#'>View More...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="photo-template">
  <div class='photo'>
    <a href='<%= url %>' target='_blank'>
      <img class='main' src='<%= photo %>' width='250' height='250' style='display:none;' onload='Instagram.App.showPhoto(this);'/>
    </a>
    <img class='avatar' width='40' height='40' src='<%= avatar %>' />
    <span class='heart'><strong><%= count %></strong></span>
    <span class='location'><%= longitude %> <%= latitude %></span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
// Instantiate an empty object.
var Instagram = {};

// Small object for holding important configuration data.
Instagram.Config = {
  clientID: '4895197dfce340cb9004101ce6ae9215',
  apiHost: 'https://api.instagram.com'
};


// ************************
// ** Main Application Code
// ************************
(function(){
  var photoTemplate, resource;

  function init(){
    bindEventHandlers();
    photoTemplate = _.template($('#photo-template').html());
  }

  function toTemplate(photo){
    photo = {
      count: photo.likes.count,
      avatar: photo.user.profile_picture,
      photo: photo.images.low_resolution.url,
      url: photo.link,
      longitude: photo.location && photo.location.longitude,
      latitude: photo.location && photo.location.latitude
    };

    return photoTemplate(photo);
  }

  function toScreen(photos){
    var photos_html = '';

    $('.paginate a').attr('data-max-tag-id', photos.pagination.next_max_id)
                    .fadeIn();

    $.each(photos.data, function(index, photo){
      photos_html += toTemplate(photo);
    });

    $('div#photos-wrap').append(photos_html);
  }

  function generateResource(tag){
    var config = Instagram.Config, url;

    if(typeof tag === 'undefined'){
      throw new Error("Resource requires a tag. Try searching for cats.");
    } else {
      // Make sure tag is a string, trim any trailing/leading whitespace and take only the first 
      // word, if there are multiple.
      tag = String(tag).trim().split(" ")[0];
    }

    url = config.apiHost + "/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?callback=?&client_id=" + config.clientID;

    return function(max_id){
      var next_page;
      if(typeof max_id === 'string' && max_id.trim() !== '') {
        next_page = url + "&max_id=" + max_id;
      }
      return next_page || url;
    };
  }

  function paginate(max_id){    
    $.getJSON(generateUrl(tag), toScreen);
  }

  function search(tag){
    resource = generateResource(tag);
    $('.paginate a').hide();
    $('#photos-wrap *').remove();
    fetchPhotos();
  }

  function fetchPhotos(max_id){
    $.getJSON(resource(max_id), toScreen);
  }

  function bindEventHandlers(){
    $('body').on('click', '.paginate a.btn', function(){
      var tagID = $(this).attr('data-max-tag-id');
      fetchPhotos(tagID);
      return false;
    });

    // Bind an event handler to the `submit` event on the form
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){

      // Stop the form from fulfilling its destinty.
      e.preventDefault();

      // Extract the value of the search input text field.
      var tag = $('input.search-tag').val().trim();

      // Invoke `search`, passing `tag` (unless tag is an empty string).
      if(tag) {
        search(tag);
      };

    });

  }

  function showPhoto(p){
    $(p).fadeIn();
  }

  // Public API
  Instagram.App = {
    search: search,
    showPhoto: showPhoto,
    init: init
  };
}());

$(function(){
  Instagram.App.init();

  // Start with a search on cats; we all love cats.
  Instagram.App.search('cats');  
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Eg4jK/)

Comment: I've seen a way in PHP to filter the results to only show the pictures with location elements; can this be done in JS as well? Ultimately, I want to take the location information and display it on google maps so you can see the coordinates on a map.

Comment: It would be my guess that you could filter client side with Javascript, I can't see why not.